# Poorer R2 score than baseline when even default parameters are used in GridSearchCV for RandomForestRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest, gridsearchcv

My problem is that I am trying to tune a RandomForestRegressor. On doing Cross Validation as well as Train Test Split method with default params, I get an R2 score of around 0.85 to 0.90
When I try to find the best parameters using GridSearchCV, I get the best R2 at around 0.60 to 0.62. Please note that I had included my the default params in my grid as well. (So that if the default is the best setting, it should be there)

I have tried many approaches like changing grid values (and including the default params back to the grid). But it does not even get closer to what default setting brought to me.

Please find the code here

```
my_steps = list()
my_steps.append(('pt_transformer', PowerTransformer(method='box-cox')))
my_steps.append(('model', RandomForestRegressor()))
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=steps)

cv = KFold(n_splits=10, 
           random_state=1, 
           shuffle=True)
# evaluate the model using cross-validation
scores = cross_validate(pipeline, 
                        X, 
                        y, 
                        scoring=['r2', 'neg_mean_absolute_error'], 
                        cv=cv, 
                        n_jobs=-1)

print('Average R2 test score: ', scores['test_r2'].mean())
print('Average MAE test score: ', np.mean([abs(s) for s in scores['test_neg_mean_absolute_error']]))
```

This gives an **R2 score of 0.85 to 0.90**
To improve this further, I chosen to do a hyperparameter tuning, with following basic params

```
parameters= {'model__max_depth' : [None, 50, 100, 150, 200],
             'model__max_leaf_nodes': [None, 5, 10],
             'model__max_samples': [None, 10, 20, 50],
             'model__max_depth': [None, 100, 150]}
```

This is followed by following:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipe,       
                    param_grid = parameters,          
                    cv = 5,
                    scoring='r2',                     
                    n_jobs = -1,
                    verbose=3)
grid.fit(X, y)
print(grid.best_params_)  
print(grid.best_score_)
```

The best score I get here is **0.6067**.

P.S Please note that all those None are default setting for those params.

Thank you!!

Comment: `model__max_depth` is included twice in the `parameters`.

Comment: Yes, it was an issue. But I can't understand how could it dent the performance? What if we feed this dictionary another key?  for example, 'model__max_depth': [None, 100, 150] and 'model__max_depth': [None, 50, 100, 150, 200]. 

couldn't it just take a union?

Comment: (My bad, that part wasn't an answer but nonetheless I wanted to make sure it was addressed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These measure different things:

```py
KFold(n_splits=10)

GridSearchCV(cv=5)
```

The first sees 90% of the data during training and scores `0.9`. The second sees 80% of the data during training and scores `0.6`.

The results should be more consistent if the number of cross validation splits are the same.

Comment: Wow! that was the problem. Sounds like I need to readdress my concepts on KFolds :) 

Thank you.

Comment: Model evaluation is a bit of an art between interpreting metrics and setting up the problem. This answer explains the difference, but it is a *little* odd how different those scores are. You might want to inspect the predictions closer before diving into grid search (e.g. [prediction error display](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_cv_predict.html)), it could be over/underfitting in some regions.